# gitlab runner cache "cache factory not found"

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, minio

I'm trying to get caching working on my Kubernetes powered Gitlab Runner.
I've set up a custom S3 Minio Deployment running on `minio:9000` and configured the `config.toml` file using a ConfigMap with this content:

```
concurrent = 10 # This sets the maximum number of concurrent CI pods
check_interval = 10

[[runners]]
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "cache"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "minio:9000"
      AccessKey = "xxx"
      SecretKey = "xxx"
      BucketName = "runners-cache"
      Insecure = true
```

Using the Minio web interface, I've made sure there is a `runners-cache` bucket present.

However, inside the job I get:

```
Checking cache for default...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted.
```

And inside the logs on the runner, I get:

```
 Could not create cache adapter
 cache factory not found: factory for cache adapter "" was not registered
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you can have a "free floating" cache declaration without the accompanying runner; you will likely get a lot better mileage by using [the env-vars for the runner pods](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/v0.11.0/templates/_cache.tpl#L13) the way they do it in their runner helm chart

Comment: What do you mean by "free floating"?

Comment: That TOML results in `{"runners": [{"cache": ...}]}` but doesn't define the runner to which the cache applies, and while I admit I didn't go spelunking around in the runner golang code, I would not guess it says "oh, then it must apply to all of them", I would guess you configured an anonymous runner's cache. The fact that you have that config _and_ this question implies that it for sure did not do what you expected, whereas I have production experience that the env-vars applied to the Pods does work